# Add event listener when a `<div>` tag changes size on screen

Tags: d3.js

There's a collapsible sidebar on my webpage.  When I collapse it, I want the `svg` element on the page to resize to take up all of the new blank space.

The function that resizes the `svg` is working.  However, it is not being triggered when the sidebar is collapsed.

I have tried:

`d3.select("#mydivHoldingSVG").on("resize", MyResize)`

Where `#mydivHoldingSVG` is a `<div>` and `MyResize` is the function to resize the `svg`.

When the sidebar is collapsed, the `<div>` element increases in size (as inspected via Google Chrome developer view), which I thought constituted a "resize".

If the *window* is resized, that is, if I use:

`d3.select(window).on("resize", MyResize)`

Then the `svg` resizes correctly.

I have looked at the list of [standard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Standard_events) to see if one can be applied to the `div` element (`#mydivHoldingSVG`) but I'm not seeing an obvious "when a div element changes" event.

Is there an eventListener that can be added on a `<div>` element being resized or changed?

Comment: Voted to closed you have not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ErikPhilips no offense but I don't see the `d3.js` tag anywhere on your profile; are you authoritative enough to say this question lacks enough detail for an example?  I tried to distill the question down to the necessary details.

Comment: As far as I know, `onresize` is an event listener fired _only_ when the document view (window) is resized. There's no specific resize event listener for an element. Are you using bootstrap for the collapsible sidebar? If yes, you can use [collapsible callbacks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events) to determine the resize and if not, you can include custom callbacks on `#mydivHoldingSVG` collapse.

Comment: @NickBraunagel I'm not an authoritative on anything on SO.  But I know enough of html, css, and javascript to know that if *I need to even attempt to try this*, I need a complete example that tries to do what you want.  That code simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist is that you should do it another way: the `resize` event *only* pertains to the window and will not fire on any other element.

The cleanest way to solve this problem would be call `MyResize` when you call whatever function is collapsing your sidebar, rather than trying to indirectly listen for the sidebar being collapsed.